# how to change the icon/logo for the push notification in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, push

i am able to receive the push notification and below is my code written in

```
 let push = Push.init({
        android: {
            senderID: '907xxxxx860',
            icon: 'icon'
        },
        ios: {
            alert: 'true',
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
      });
```

i am testing in android version 5.

in my assets folder i have an image `assets/images/home/KmartLogo.png` in this path. i want this image as my logo for the android.

how can i achieve this. according to this documentation [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) i am trying to give the path in like this `icon: 'icon'` in to this `icon:assets/images/home/KmartLogo.png` but it is not working how can i change my logo

update notification image i am getting [image: img]

Comment: do you mean it show white icon? if it so, that just specific problem for Android 5 only because of Android 5 use stencil icon.

Comment: maybe you got the path wrong.. try `./assets/images/home/KmartLogo.png`

Comment: i tried the way you have given i am not able to get the logo @suraj

Comment: @Djamware if so how can we solve that issue

Comment: It's not an issue, just make stencil icon with the transparent background. Any color in Android 5 push notification icon will be white.

Answer (score 0):

The `icon` name **should not include the extension**.

[**Doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/#AndroidPushOptions)

> The name of a drawable resource to use as the small-icon. The name
>   should not include the extension.

```
android: {
            senderID: '907xxxxx860',
            icon: './assets/images/home/KmartLogo'
        },
```

Comment: when i tried your answer i my visual studio editor show this issue `[ts] Argument of type '{ android: { senderID: string; image: string; }; ios: { alert: string; badge: true; sound: string...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PushOptions'.
       Types of property 'android' are incompatible.
         Type '{ senderID: string; image: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AndroidPushOptions'.
           Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'image' does not exist in type 'AndroidPushOptions'.`

Comment: I am still not able to update the icon of push notification

Comment: no check my updated question with the notification i am reciving

Comment: in official website they give this line for icon `The name of a drawable resource to use as the small-icon. The name should not include the extension.` does this means i have to give only small icon if so how much size it should be

Comment: yes, it should be very small. check with very small one first.

Comment: i am using an image width of 311 pixels and height of 365 pixels

Comment: oh .. which is very large. create very small one 40x40

Comment: i checked with 40 width and 40 height but same thing happens, it is not solved

Comment: it seems icon must be `bitmap`.see this:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html